# Linked-list with different class types

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I am trying to write a linked list to store different data types.
So here is my issue, I am coding **air hockey table simulation**, it includes 3 classes, a normal disc, shrinking and exploding disc, and with one Linked list I can go through all my discs and check some stuff.

I am using **Templates**, but some how I cant figure out how to use.

Here is my node template

```
template<typename TYPE>
struct Disks_List{
    TYPE d;
    Disks_List<TYPE> *next;
};
struct Walls_List{
    Wall w;
    Walls_List *next;
};
template<typename TYPE>
class Board {
private:
    Disks_List *disks; //Error here I cant leave it without cast, but what I need is to use this list for my three types of discs.
    Walls_List *walls;
```

Would be happy for any links that could help.

Comment: On your error line, replace `Disks_List` with `Disks_List<TYPE>`.

Comment: @WillEccles Yes I know the error, the point that when I use `Disks_List<TYPE>`, I have to define `Disks_List<Disc>` for example. but what I needed is a Linked-list for 3 types and not just for `Disc`

Comment: You need one list which contains 3 different data types?

Comment: @WillEccles 3 classes. used inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: Why does `Board` take a `TYPE`, if you don't use it? You either need to use it and only store one list of `disks` (or one per `TYPE`), or remove the template argument and derive them from a common base class in order to use them all via a base pointer. But you should just use `std::list< std::unique_ptr<MysteriousDiskBase> >`, not roll your own container.

Comment: Board defines the game, have walls and discs lists.
Using STL(list/vector etc) is forbidden, I have to code it without using those library's.

Comment: Note that `Walls_List` is basically `Disks_List<Wall>`. `Disks_List` is a bad name for this type and it's not to well designed. I recommend creating `template<typename T> class SinglyLinkedList { ... };` and add a `Node` type as inner type to this template class. This way you can make `SinglyLinkedList` responsible for resource (de)allocation which will result in higher quality code. As for handling different types of disks:to put them in the same list they need to be derived from a common base type(`DiskBase`?)which needs to be used as type parameter for the list(`SinglyLinkedList<DiskBase>`)

Comment: Got it, I will go for it, thank you! @fabian

Answer (score 1):

On the line you commented, you should replace `Disks_List` with `Disks_List<TYPE>`, as the template requires an argument.